# How can I get the full email address of a list with the server object model?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, email

I have a list that is enabled to receive emails. On the list settings in the web interface I can see the entire email address (for example `MyList@example.net`), but I'd like to get this email address using PowerShell and the server object model.

So far I have only figured out how the get the email alias:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb https://example.net/sites/Test
$list = $web.Lists['My List']
$list.EmailAlias # Returns only 'MyList'
```

This is only the part before the `@` symbol - how do I get the rest? I'm asking for SharePoint 2013, although I imagine it is the same for 2010 and 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb https://example.net/sites/Test
$list = $web.Lists['My List']
$list.EmailAlias # Returns only 'MyList'
$service = Get-SPService | ?{$_.TypeName -match 'incoming'}
Write-Host "$($list.EmailAlias)@$($service.ServerDisplayAddress)"
```

The fully qualified address is not stored on the List object so we must get it from the Incoming Email service itself.

Comment: Thanks! `Get-SPService` doesn't appear to be available on 2013 though. `(Get-SPServiceInstance |? { $_.TypeName -match 'incoming' }).Service.ServerDisplayAddress` seems do to the trick!

Comment: True, my bad. Glad you got it worked around.